# Swift Package with C++ builds in Xcode but not on CLI

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c++, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package that includes C++ and ObjC code.

It builds & runs with no issues in the Xcode 13.3 IDE and when building it as part of an app using `xcodebuild` on CLI, but when I try to build it on the command-line with `swift build` it fails with several errors (these are representative errors; there are many more):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:523:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString, Protocol;
^

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:525:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
typedef NSString * NSExceptionName NS_TYPED_EXTENSIBLE_ENUM;
        ^
```

It looks like the compiler is trying to compile ObjC headers as C++, but I'm not quite certain what is happening.

Is there something more I must do (command-line options, Package.swift additions, etc.) to make my package compile & run using `swift build`?

Here is a link to the package if you want to look at source or try it yourself:
https://github.com/TralaEngineering/verovio

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue described [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/5923). You may try to use `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and build using `xcodebuild` instead of `swift build` until Swift version with a fix is released, hopefully it will be included into next(14.3) Xcode version.